# show results of array sorted by unique day

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'd like my array to be sorted by unique day and only show the day value once with all the times for that day included.

Desired Example:

**Informal**

**Monday:** 2PM to 3PM, 3PM to 4PM, 4PM to 5PM

**Tuesday:** 2PM to 3PM, 3PM to 4PM, 4PM to 5PM

**Wednesday:** 2PM to 3PM, 3PM to 4PM, 4PM to 5PM

**Thursday:** 2PM to 3PM, 3PM to 4PM, 4PM to 5PM

---

Currently I get this with the day iterated each time.
Monday: 2PM to 3PM, Monday 3PM to 4PM, Monday 4PM to 5PM
Tuesday: 2PM to 3PM, Tuesday 3PM to 4PM, Tuesday 4PM to 5PM
and so on.

---

Here's my array:

```
["Informal"]=> array(12) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(6) "Monday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "2 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "3 PM" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(6) "Monday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "3 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "4 PM" } } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(6) "Monday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "4 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "5 PM" } } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(7) "Tuesday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "2 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "3 PM" } } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(7) "Tuesday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "3 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "4 PM" } } 
[5]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(7) "Tuesday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "4 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "5 PM" } } 
[6]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(9) "Wednesday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "2 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "3 PM" } } 
[7]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(9) "Wednesday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "3 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "4 PM" } } 
[8]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(9) "Wednesday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "4 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "5 PM" } } 
[9]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(8) "Thursday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "2 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "3 PM" } } 
[10]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(8) "Thursday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "3 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "4 PM" } } 
[11]=> array(1) { ["Schedule"]=> array(4) { ["program"]=> string(8) "Informal" ["day"]=> string(8) "Thursday" ["start_time"]=> string(4) "4 PM" ["end_time"]=> string(4) "5 PM" } }  }
```

---

is it possible with this array or do I need to modify my sql query?
I've tried a GROUP BY 'day' but it did not work. I've also tried nesting a foreach loop of the times within a foreach loop of the day which I think is the way to go but I'm not getting it correct.

here's the php/html without it being nested

```
<h1>Schedules</h1>
<h2>Room 1</h2>
<?php
$array = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $data[$row['Schedule']['program']][] = $row;
}
?>
<?php foreach ($array as $program => $schedules) { ?>
<h3><?php echo $program; ?></h3>
<fieldset class="programs">
<!-- data rows -->
<?php foreach ($schedules as $key => $schedule) :
echo $schedule['Schedule']['day']. " : " .$schedule['Schedule']['start_time'];?> to <?php echo $schedule['Schedule']['end_time'] . " <br /> ";
endforeach; ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What is your sql query? depending on your table structure you could possibly use GROUP_CONCAT to group the scheduled hours for each day to a comma separated list that you could just then `explode` in the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($array as $program => $schedules) { ?>
<h3><?php echo $program; ?></h3>
<fieldset class="programs">
<!-- data rows -->
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach ($schedules as $key => $schedule) :

    if ($i === 0) {
       echo $schedule['Schedule']['day'] . ': ';
       ++$i;
    }
echo $schedule['Schedule']['start_time'];?> to <?php echo $schedule['Schedule']['end_time'];
if (isset($schedules[$key +1 ]['Schedule']['day'])) {
if ($schedule['Schedule']['day'] === $schedules[$key +1 ]['Schedule']['day']) {
echo ', ';
} else {
    echo '</br> ' .$schedules[$key +1 ]['Schedule']['day'] . ': ';
}
}
endforeach; ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This looks pretty good as well but I get an undefined offset for both lines with [$key +1] after it returns the desired results. Do I need to unset?

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Schedules</h1>
<h2>Room 1</h2>
<?php
$array = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $data[$row['Schedule']['program']][] = $row;
}
?>
<?php foreach ($array as $program => $schedules) { ?>
<h3><?php echo $program; ?></h3>
<fieldset class="programs">
<p>
<!-- data rows -->
<?php $current = ''; ?>
<php $counter = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($schedules as $key => $schedule) :
echo $current != $schedule['Schedule']['day'] ? '</p><p>'.$schedule['Schedule']['day']. " : " : '';
echo ($counter!=0 ? ', ' : '') . $schedule['Schedule']['start_time'];?> to <?php echo $schedule['Schedule']['end_time'];

$current = $schedule['Schedule']['day'];
$counter++;
endforeach; ?>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

note: code not tested.

Edit: Code updated. This is not the best way to do it, but it works. Better option might be create query that will get all days and concated hours as @patrik suggested below.

Comment: That looks good but is there a way to put each new day on next line?

Answer (score 0):

Using CONCAT with GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT
 day
 GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(start_time, " to ", end_time) ) as hours
FROM
 sometable
GROUP BY
 day
```

Your returned rows from the mysql query Would have the structure like

```
array( 
   array("day"=>"Monday","hours"=>"2pm to 3pm, 3pm to 4pm, 4pm to 5pm"),
   array("day"=>"Tuesday","hours"=>"2pm to 3pm, 3pm to 4pm, 4pm to 5pm")
)
```